# Resource management with thousands of sequential instantiations of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, garbage-collection, instantiation

Given a spreadsheet of a few thousand URLs, I will loop over them and for each, instantiate a `Page()` class then call two methods, the first to get the page, the second to parse with `lxml`. (`urllib2` & `lxml` in my experience do their stuff quite quickly, which is why I don't think I will need to use multithreading, which I have no experience with anyway):

```
class Page(object):
    """Representation of any page to be scraped"""

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url


    def fetch(self):
        """ Fetch the URL. Return raw (text) source."""

        self.source = # do urllib stuff

    def parse(self):
        """ Extract page elements with lxml """
```

I have minimal knowledge of memory management in Python. Will it be necessary or prudent to do any of the following?

- Call `del` on the Page objects once I am done with their methods
- Employ a context manager (`with Page(url) as page:`)
- Any other technique for minimizing resource usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ferdy's answer is substantially correct. But in general, you only have to manage memory if you are using a lot of it.

As I understand it, you are going to instantiate a Page, fetch the contents, call page.parse() on them, and then ... what?

If you are not holding the urls, and not holding the page contents, then the Python GC will reclaim things as needed.

If you are referencing the contents inside the `page` object, and you also reference the contents in some other data structure, all the `del` calls in the world won't help you, because the contents will be much larger than whatever little bits of memory you get back by releasing the URLs.

Short answer: don't worry about this until it becomes a problem, then create a new post on SO and describe the actual problem you end up with.

Comment: For the additional explanation, you get the nod.

Answer (score 1):

From what you're revealing it would be sufficient to re-use one Page object again and again, because you mentioned, you want to iterate through all your pages sequentially.